# Is feeding a stray dog an act of sadaqah? Are the ahadith that relate to this authentic?

Tags: animals, sadaqah, dogs

I know about a hadith that says feeding the hungry is sadaqah.  So I feed the stray dogs. Please let me know if it is an act of sadaqah.

Also, I heard a few more hadith like, feeding the dogs will not give any returns on the day of ressurection, because dogs are prohibited in Islam.  One more hadith I heard was once Prophet S.A.W was sitting under a tree and was bitten by a red ant, and the prophet ordered the sahabas to burn that tree along with the ants.  The above 2 hadiths really made me worried: How can Islam be so inhuman towards the animals, and how could our rasool be so hard-hearted?

Are these ahadith authentic, or fake ahadith being circulated? And is feeding those poor creature a sadaqah?

Comment: "I heard" Does not really help anyone in answering your question, at least quote the Hadith preferably with its narrators. If you tried finding them and haven't found anything, then that is a good sign that they don't exist in the first place. As these so called Hadiths are contradictory to the basic teachings of Islam

Comment: You can feed dogs http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/126 and any other creature http://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/33/30.

Comment: As for the ants story, it was not the Prophet. It was another prophet http://sunnah.com/muslim/39/200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a Jewish prostitute who gave a dog some water and God forgave her for that.

Abu Huraira reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Allah had once forgiven a prostitute. She passed by a dog panting near a well. Seeing that thirst had nearly killed him, she took off her shoe, tied it to her scarf, and drew up some water. Allah forgave her for that.”

Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 3143, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2245

Comment: Your welcome ! (:

Comment: Again I do not understand why I have been downvoted this is ridiculous.

Comment: Do not worry brother. it must be some idiot animal-hater who is muslim just by name.

Answer (score 2):

Brother

That Hadith about burning the entire tree was not about Prophet Muhammad SAWS,

It was narrated by Prophet Muhammad about some other prophet who did that. Kindly watch out for Christians and Jews who fabricate falsehood to intentionally degrade ISLAM.

The right Hadith is as follows:

Abu Hurayrah (Radhiallaahu Anhu) reports, I heard the Prophet (Pbuh) saying, A certain Prophet from the many Prophets (Alayhis salaam) was resting under the shade of a tree. An ant bit him. He instructed his belongings to be removed from there and immediately ordered the heap of Ants to be burnt. Allah Ta’ala revealed to him “Was it not only Ant that hurt you and you have ordered a full nation of ants to be destroyed who are engaged in the invocation of Allah Taala? Was it not one ant?”